# scanf on non-STDIN input

Tags: c, input, stdin, scanf

Is it possible to run `scanf` on input that it is not STDIN? What I mean is if I have a `string="hello 1 2 3"`, can I run scanf on it to extract the string and three integers?

Is there another function that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sscanf` on a string (info [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/))

`fscanf` on a file (info [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/))

similarly [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) and [fprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fprintf/) to write to a string/file.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a string, [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/) would be more appropriate. The title of your question implies reading from a different stream, for which there are other similar functions (see  [fscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/)).